# How to narrow type according to argument's value

Tags: typescript

How to narrowing the lib's type as the demo codes showing?
Use `factory` to generate a new function `fnP`, how to get the exactly type but not `any`?

```
const libA = {
  p: () => 0,
  q: () => 1,
};
const libB = {
  x: () => 'x',
  y: () => 'y',
};

type TLib = 'a' | 'b';
type TKey<T extends TLib> = T extends 'a'
  ? keyof typeof libA
  : T extends 'b'
  ? keyof typeof libB
  : never;

function factory<T extends TLib>(library: T, key: TKey<T>) {
  // how to narrowing the lib's type?
  const lib = {
    a: libA,
    b: libB,
  }[library][key];

  return function () {
    return lib();
  };
}

const fnP = factory('a', 'p');
fnP(); // how to return the correct type?
```

Comment: The only way I know of to get the compiler to infer this is to use the technique described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I apply the refactoring there to your code, I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8zMN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Not perfect but useful enough.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What is "imperfect" about it?  It it just the complexity/unintuitiveness of it?  Or is it actually not doing something right with the types?  Does "useful enough" mean you're likely to accept an answer if I spend the effort to write one up (with explanations and sources)?  Or are you looking for something else here?  Just trying to figure out how best to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz It's not quite right under typescript v4. `<_LibMap[L][keyof _LibMap[L]]>` makes a type error.

Comment: Does the question depend on legacy versions of TypeScript? If so, please [edit] to specify the range of versions you need support for. (But note that you should probably upgrade to the latest release unless you want to have increasing difficulties over time.) Either way, could you please answer the rest of the questions I asked earlier? How shall I proceed? I can either write up my answer if supporting old TS versions isn’t a requirement, or disengage if it is.

Comment: @jcalz No, it's not depend on legacy versions of TypeScript. You can write an answer. Thanks.

Comment: (In my answer I show an additional, alternate formulation for `LibRet` which you might want to try if you're using an older TS version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I will give the object `{ a: libA, b: libB }` the name `libMap`, for ease of discussion:

```
const libMap = {
    a: libA,
    b: libB
};
```

---

If you want a single code block like `libMap[library][key]()` to be strongly typed given a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `L` for `library`, then the type of `libMap` needs to be written in a special way that allows the compiler to see the correlation.  This technique is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), mostly as a way of dealing with correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), but since part of that fix is to switch from unions to generics, it applies here also.

The idea is that the type of `libMap` should be seen as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some "basic" key-value type so that when you write `libMap[library]`, the compiler sees it as a generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type, and can understand the result as a generic relationship between the type `L`.

Here's one way to do it.  First let's just rename `libMap` out of the way to `_libMap`, so we can use TypeScript's [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get its inferred type and use that to build the special version of that type:

```
const _libMap = {
    a: libA,
    b: libB
}

type _LibMap = typeof _libMap;
```

Now we can write `LibKey`, the mapped type between the keys of `libMap` and the keys of the object at those keys:

```
type LibKey = { [L in keyof _LibMap]: keyof _LibMap[L] };
```

and we can also write `LibRet`, the mapped type between the keys of `libMap` and the return type of the methods contained in the objects at those keys:

```
type LibRet = { [L in keyof _LibMap]:
    // for TS versions before 5.1:
    // _LibMap[L][keyof _LibMap[L]] extends (
    //    ...args: any) => infer R ? R : never    
    ReturnType<_LibMap[L][keyof _LibMap[L]]>
};
```

(Note, if you have an issue with the `ReturnType` line, you might try replacing it with the commented out version.)

Finally, we can reconstruct the type of `LibMap` as mapped type over `LibKey` using both `LibMap` and `LibRet`, and assign `_libMap` to the intended variable `libMap` [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as `LibMap`:

```
type LibMap = { [L in keyof LibKey]: Record<LibKey[L], () => LibRet[L]> };

const libMap: LibMap = _libMap;
```

The fact that this last line compiles with no error means that our `LibMap` type is considered compatible with that of `_LibMap`.  This might all look like a lot of type juggling with no effect: after all, the values `_libMap` and `libMap` are the same, and the types `_LibMap` and `LibMap` are equivalent.  But the TypeScript compiler sees them differently; only `LibMap` is expressed in the form necessary for the correlation to be maintained.

Let's see it:

```
function factory<L extends keyof LibMap>(library: L, key: LibKey[L]) {
    const lib = libMap[library][key];

    return function () {
        return lib();
    };
}
// function factory<L extends "a" | "b">(
//   library: L, key: LibKey[L]
// ): () => LibRet[L]
```

That compiles cleanly, and the compiler sees the return type of `factory()` as `() => LibRet[L]`.  That means inside of the function, `libMap[library]` is seen as type `LibMap[L]`, which is seen as equivalent to `Record<LibKey[L], () => LibRet[L]>`.  And since `key` is of type `LibKey[L]`, then `libMap[library][key]` (a.k.a. `lib`) is seen as `() => LibRet[L]`.  Inside the returned function then, `lib()` is seen as returning `LibRet[L]`.

So that means when you call `factory()`, the returned value should be strongly typed, as desired:

```
const fnP = factory('a', 'p');
console.log(fnP().toFixed(1)); // 0.0
// succeeds, fnP() seen as number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSwEYEEYF4YG8CwAoGQmABwC4YAKASgwD4YAGAGnyJgEdzq6YBGFvAF8A3PlCRYiJACEM2VkQAeXGunoByReoFsAnip7rd2-CPxjw0GAH0pAWQCGxObgJEH5KSh1Ekn5NKm+FC6xACmNgAyyI7OmCHhIABmNvZOonjBoRHRSADSYbouMADakTAIYDAA1oXJUTFOALrktbr11rmxZU0wZpl4CTnIAEphsJhYpeWVNXUpnY3ELQqEAPRrMEkgAE4wACoAyjAAbmE7EAiWMEhh2zsRAKwAdLykqzAbDUjdkU0lbQ6XScPV6YUUUDCYAAJhBKB8vkRnsiHDsAOYQcgOMC6VT0SpJc4wEYwAD8xJg5DAYTOeyIHzGUAArjswPtsgAeRY-EF-AHzb6-JpNWimDJZcIwYFxbDTCpVQEpXIFXQtYlhUA7aEc5WFHpMSh4qWjcY9ej9cRWNJkY08mW2JbivBJJlgYBQK5VJIOd27XQ6mDgyEwuGK22xWgUKQ7VH6KUGtrkXW6Ho0Kb0tyES2SZBya0laOx-5tJoZNgPZmsrau92ew3yTNsGAVllVKTUMtN9abbPwZAGNS2xk9D79QTmPC9pJgAAKcm9vp2ugo6gc2hg6mI6ioGUtIDgYWecBAaIo05n1GeUBAADEEIowtCKLwqDvPpsGM8GPggA)